# Proving uniform continuity of trigonometric function arctan

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

In my assignment I have to prove that the following function is uniformly continuous:

$$f(x) = \arctan x \cdot \sin\left(\frac{1} {x}\right) $$ in the **open interval** $(0,\infty) $.

I thought I'd prove the one side limits $ x\to 0^+$ and $ x\to \infty^-$.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty^-}=\frac{\pi} {2}\cdot0=0.$$

For the second limit I thought using the squeeze theorem. Please let me know if I made a mistake:

$$0\le \arctan x \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1} {x} \right)\le  \arctan x .$$

Therefore, from the squeeze theorem:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \arctan x \cdot\sin\left(\frac{1} {x}\right) =0$$

Since $\arctan$ and $\sin$ are continuous always when it is defined, we can say that the function is uniformly continuous, since the one side limits exists.

I have only one concern here: zero is not defined here, in the open interval from the beginning. Is it a problem to use the squeeze theorem here? If it is, thought I'd use $\frac {x} {x+1} $ instead of $0$.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks. Why isn't it right? Which side of the inequality? Thanks.

Comment: Not really, just because multiplying by $\arctan x$ dampens the wild behaviour of $\sin(1/x)$ near $0$. The system is getting upset at the length of the comment string, I will delete most of mine and suggest you also prune.

Comment: Yes, you can prove the limit is $0$. If $|f(x)|$ has limit $0$ then $f(x)$ has limit $0$.

Comment: Thank you! I am so grateful for your help. @AndréNicolas

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**To find the limit:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\arctan(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}\arctan(x).x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}\arctan(x).\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$=1.0=0$$